# Can I add tabindex attribute to ::before

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a label element wherein I add an image to it from css.

```
<label id="label1" tabindex="0">Some Text</label>
```

**CSS**

```
label#label1:before {
 content: url(../../img/icon-radio_unselected.svg);}
```

Now when I reach this label using **tab** key, it highlights the entire label along with the image which in my case, the image should only be highlighted. I was thinking of adding the tabindex to the **::before** selector, but not sure if this is at all possible.

Can anyone please suggest if this is the right way or should I use a different approach altogether.

Comment: No...pseudo-elements cannot receive `focus` or attributes as they not actually elements.

Comment: If this is related to styling on being tabbed to / receiving focus, perhaps you should show us **that** stylling.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I'm thinking of removing the image being set by the label and rather moving it out of that label.